# Mockito - Função que recebe jsonObject retornar false

Tags: java, mockito

```
public class ParseProcessoTest {
    private final String PATTERN_DATA_HORA = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("json qualquer");
    JSONObject jsonMov = new JSONObject("json qualquer 2");
    ParseProcesso parseProcesso = Mockito.spy(new ParseProcesso(jsonObject));
    JSONObject spyJson = Mockito.spy(jsonMov);


    @Before
    public void init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when(parseProcesso.movimentacaoTemAnexo(spyJson)).thenReturn(false);
    }

    @Test
    public void testaSeRetornaFalsoMetodoMovimentacaoTemAnexo(){
        Assertions.assertThat(parseProcesso.movimentacaoTemAnexo(spyJson)).isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    public void testaParse() throws IOException {
        Processo processoTeste = parseProcesso.parse();
        //testes
```

Tenho essa classe de teste, que testa o parse de um conjunto de informações. Porém, eu quero que o método seguinte retorne false:

```
public boolean movimentacaoTemAnexo(JSONObject movimento){
    return (int) movimento.get("qtd_anexo") > 0;
}
```

Já tentei:

```
when(parseProcesso.movimentacaoTemAnexo(anyObject())).thenReturn(false);
```

Que resulta:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at br.com.ParseProcesso.movimentacaoTemAnexo(ParseProcesso.java:208)
at testes.ParseProcessoTest.init(ParseProcessoTest.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Pensei que ao utilizar o when.thenReturn, seria como se pulasse a execução do método em questão. Só traria o retorno. O que posso fazer?

Comment: Lançou um NullPointerException... Alterei o método movimentacaoTemAnexo() utilizando o Optional.ofNullable para evitar essa exception, mas mesmo assim...

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta! E as partes são respectivamente: o return do método movimentacaoTemAnexo() e o when(parseProcesso.movimentacaoTemAnexo(anyObject())).thenReturn(false);

Comment: Não, só existe esse método com esses parametros mesmo. Já havia tentado, tentei agora mas o problema continua o mesmo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67517/discussion-between-anthony-accioly-and-laaf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código caiu em um *corner case* do [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) com relação a *stubbing* em *spies*.

[**Link para a documentação relevante**](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13)

#### Tradução livre

> #### *Pegadinha* importante ao espiar objetos reais!
>
> Algumas vezes é impossível ou não é prático usar `when(Object)` para fazer o *stubbing* de espiões. Dessa forma, ao utilizar espiões por favor considere a família de métodos `doReturn|Answer|Throw()` para *stubbing*. Exemplo:
>
> ```
> List list = new LinkedList();
> List spy = spy(list);
>
> // Impossivel: o método real é chamado, então spy.get(0) dispara 
> // IndexOutOfBoundsException (a lista ainda está vazia)
> when(spy.get(0)).thenReturn("foo");
> // Você deve usar doReturn() para stubbing
> doReturn("foo").when(spy).get(0);
> ```

No seu caso, basta trocar a linha

```
when(parseProcesso.movimentacaoTemAnexo(spyJson)).thenReturn(false);
```

Para:

```
doReturn(false).when(parseProcesso).movimentacaoTemAnexo(any());
```

---

**Fonte**: [*SOen Mockito: Trying to spy on method is calling the original method*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620196/664577)